# How to edit text in a div?

Tags: html, css

So I have a navigation bar and when I hover over it, the background color turns white. I also want the text to turn black simultaneously. How to I make it do this? This is my css code:

```
.row:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: black;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: `transition` goes on the solid state.

Comment: Maybe you're not applying the row class to anything?

Answer (score 2):

The `transition` needs to be on the static property.

```css
.row {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't change the text color, only the background. thank you!

Comment: Just an example :)